# Как в freemarker отобразить html код?

Tags: spring-boot, шаблонизаторы, freemarker

Делаю небольшой проект на spring boot. И в базе у себя храню html код , как его правильно отобразить в freemarker?Есть просто отобразить через ${Chapter.text}

Он отображает на странице html код